# How to make an existing repo a sub repo of a new repo on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, version-control, frontend, repository

I have taken some challenges on [frontendmentor](https://frontendmentor.io) and created these repositories on GitHub:

> FEM-calculator-project

> FEM-Landing-page

Is it possible to move these two repositories into a new one named:

> frontendmentor-challenges

I've been stuck with this for a while now. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge in front- and backend so my answer will be based on my knowledge in Git. You can add one repo as a submodule inside the other repo. After doing that you can navigate to the submodule and deal with it as normal repo.

so for example, given that you have cloned the `frontendmentor-challenges` now navigate to it and add `FEM-calculator-project` and `FEM-Landing-page` as submodules inside `frontendmentor-challenges`.

To add submodule:

```
$ git submodule add <remote_url>  /*of the repo that you want to add as submodule*/  
$ git commit -m "comment"
$ git push
```

There is alot to know about submodules, like updating the submodule and so on. I hope this works for you :)

Comment: If delete the original repos after adding them to the new parent repo, will I still be able to work with them or they will be deleted as well?

Comment: Adding submodules inside the main repo means that you have cloned these submodules-repos to your local machine. If you deleted the content from the remote repo of a submodule and then updated or pulled (`git pull --recurse-submodules` from parent repo) or (`git pull` from inside the submodule), you will most probably lose the data from the submodule..

**so consider submodules as completely normal repos**

Answer (score 0):

Sometime, we want to add some repository (child repo) in a repository (parent repo), but want to manage child repos independently.

That's when we need submodule, you can [refer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsTthZi23VE&t=9s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org) first

add child repo to parent repo (same clone), you can check `cat .git/config`. Then, you can add, commit normally.

```
git submodule add <link child repos>
```

In some cases, you are not pulling a Git submodule but you are simply look to update your existing Git submodule in the project. Like you code on module A but need to use the new feature on module B

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

when you clone paren repos, git do not auto clone submodule, you must update and pull submodule

```
git submodule update --init
git submodule update --recursive --remote
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

when submodule is no longer use, you can remove it

```
git submodule deinit <path_to_submodule_folder> -f
git rm <path_to_submodule_folder>
git commit -m "Remove submodule" .
rm -rf .git/modules/<path_to_submodule_folder>
```

I don't use A too much either, so here are some uses I know.

Hopefully this help you.